# Retrieve easily element by JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

My question is more regarding the best way/practice how to realise one thing. Lets assume I have a possibility to create a html code for JQuery to retrieve some text value. What is the best way to do it?

I know you can just get a value using the get by id and so on, so basically I could create my own div with unique ID and by JQuery retrieve some value in it. But is this the good way? Of course another thing is that the value should not be seen by the people.

Maybe I should put the value as an attribute? Key, value pair? And get element by id and get the attribute?

So any suggestions, the best way to store one value on the page and easily retrieve it?

Thanks in advance

**An update:**

An example:
I do something as following:

```
<div id="uniqueID" style="display:none"> Value which in need </div>
```

This is some solution, then i just need to retrieve this value with JQuery, simple.
But what i whant to know is there a better way, maybe there is some special tag in HTML, or something that other people prefer, etc ...

By jquery i just say something like:

```
$("#uniqueId").val()
```

And there should not be anything more complicated queiet simple, didn't know it could be so unclear.

Comment: `Of course another thing is that the value should not be seen by the people.` If you put it in the markup, it will be seen by people.

Comment: I can view the source and find it. Unless, of course, you're not *worried about that*

Comment: "the best way to store one value on the page" can you clarify if you talking about the client side here?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. "Lets assume I have a possibility to create a html code for JQuery to retrieve some text value." - you'd select the jquery node and use `.html()`. But I guess you mean something different?

Comment: If you want to store a value in an HTML element that the user can't see use an `<input type="hidden">`, not a hidden `<div>`. But if you're going to embed data in the page like that why not create a JS variable directly?

Comment: updated: i cannot use js directly because I will do it with server side code, which will do some activities and then will have to put some special value and with this value i will be able to do some client side actvities

Comment: My point was you can use server-side code to output a script block that sets a JS variable value just as easily as you can use server-side code to output a div or other element to hold a value to be retrieved from JS.

Comment: nnnnn, how can I by servers side code create a js variable and then use on the client side, when user is browsing page ??? btw your idea about hidden input is really great, + can you organise it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want your server to embed a value in your page that is not visible to the viewer that you can then retrieve in javascript, you might as well just have your server put the value in a javascript variable directly.  There is no reason to put it in the DOM if you just need it in javascript.

For example, you can just put this in your page:

```
<script>
var myValueSetByServer = "foo";
</script>
```

Then, you can just access `myValueSetByServer` anywhere in the page javascript.  There is no need to put it in a div or on an attribute or anything like that.

If you were going to have lots of these, you could just define an object and make your values all be properties on the object:

```
<script>
var myServerValues = {prop1: "foo", prop2: "whatever", user: "fred", type: "person"};
</script>
```

---

Of course, there are many other ways to store things in the actual page like you have mentioned including a data attribute on a DOM node, the text value of a hidden DOM node, etc... but none are as simple as just putting the value in a javscript variable if you just want to use the value from javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the value you need as an attribute like

`<div id="smth" data-you-need="value"></div>.`

then get it

`$('#smth').attr('data-you-need')`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to have a PHP page on your server which looks like this:

```
<?php print "topsecretvalue" ?>
```

and load it with AJAX.

But, if you just want it to not be displayed on the visible page, and if you're fine with the fact that people will be able to find it relatively easily by looking at the source code, then just set a variable in Javascript at the top of the first script tag, and use it when needed. No need to put it somewhere in a DIV!